# How do I gradle run without any dependency checking?

Tags: java, ant, build, gradle

We have a complex set of build.gradle scripts.

Is it possible to run a task without dependency checking of any kind?

e.g.

```
gradle run
```

should just start the jvm and nothing else?

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of dependencies do you mean? do you mean task dependencies or library dependencies?

Comment: I just want to do gradle run as fast as possible because I know all dependencies have been built. I just want it to start the task ASAP.

Comment: I believe you already use Gradle daemon mode to speed up your build.

Comment: I have org.gradle.daemon=true and configureondemand=true in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to exclude module dependencies, there is a `-a`, or `--no-rebuild` option to skip other subprojects/modules.

If you want to skip the compilation, or resources tasks, you can use the `-x` option.

Comment: The `-a` and `--no-rebuild` options were [deprecated in Gradle 4.4](https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/release-notes.html) and removed in Gradle 5.0.

Comment: `--no-rebuild` is still available in Gradle (currently 7.1) https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html

Answer (score 1):

If running on bash, you can skip all dependencies like this

```
./gradlew test $(./gradlew test --dry-run | awk '/^:/ { print "-x" $1 }' | sed '$ d')
```

What this does is simply

- to do a dry-run of the build, to detect all dependencies and
- build a command line with all required -x flags.

Notice:

- you can use the Gradle `--console plain` flag if you want to see the initial output without the pretty-print features of Gradle
- the sed allows to skip the last line... awk being quite complex to do the same...